# Selenium + webdriverio - How to retrieve a var produced by the page JS initialisation?

Tags: node.js, selenium, webdriver, phantomjs, webdriver-io

In the acceptance test suite that I'm developing (featuring mocha, sinon and chai at the top of the stack), **I am able to load a page in phantomjs and perform all sorts of operations** according to the examples available around the web.

**The only thing that eludes me is the retrieval of JS variables produced during the startup of the page.** I am enclosing a complete example here that shows how the variable `app` cannot be tested, whereas `jQuery` can.

The only difference between the two is that `app` is produced by the run of a `$(document).ready(function() {... create var app ...})`

The error I get is `maximum call stack exceeded` (?!?!?!?)

**What could I do to perform the check of app when this is available?** Maybe something using promises? I can't see all this clearly(**).

Here is the error stack:

```
19:29:02.918 INFO [14] org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet - Executing: [execute script: return app, []] at URL: /session/73437950-3c14-4392-81ed-c6bd83c3f3fb/execute)
19:29:06.481 WARN [14] org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet - Exception thrown
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: {"errorMessage":"Maximum call stack size exceeded.","request":{"headers":{"Accept":"application/json, image/png","Connection":"Keep-Alive","Content-Length":"33","Content-Type":"application/json; charset=utf-8","Host":"localhost:1693"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"args\":[],\"script\":\"return app\"}","url":"/execute","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"execute","directory":"/","path":"/execute","relative":"/execute","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/execute","queryKey":{},"chunks":["execute"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/9ca480b0-3c34-11e4-b1c7-0d43d6ab90ff/execute"}}
Command duration or timeout: 3.56 seconds
Build info: version: '2.39.0', revision: 'ff23eac', time: '2013-12-16 16:11:15'
System info: host: 'vagrant-xxx-yyyy', ip: '127.0.0.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.2.0-60-generic', java.version: '1.7.0_65'
Session ID: 9ca480b0-3c34-11e4-b1c7-0d43d6ab90ff
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver
Capabilities [{platform=LINUX, acceptSslCerts=false, javascriptEnabled=true, browserName=phantomjs, rotatable=false, driverVersion=1.1.0, locationContextEnabled=false, version=1.9.7, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=false, browserConnectionEnabled=false, webStorageEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, proxy={proxyType=direct}, applicationCacheEnabled=false, driverName=ghostdriver, takesScreenshot=true}]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
```

Here is the test: `getTitle`, `getTagName`, `getElementSize` and `execute('return jQuery')` succeed; `execute('return app')`fails.

```
describe('AAA Test acceptance XXXXX', function(){
  var client = {}

  before(function(done) {
    client = webdriverjs.remote({
      desiredCapabilities: {
        browserName: 'phantomjs'
      },
    });
    client.init(done) // starts session and opens the browser
  });

  it('The merchant button',function(done){
    client.url('http://www.dev.xxxx.com/api/purchase/index.html')
    .getTitle(function(err,title){
      expect(err).to.be.null
      expect(title).to.have.string('Mobile Payment');
    })
    .getTagName('.merchant-div',function(err,tagName){
      expect(err).to.be.null
      expect(tagName).to.be.equal('div')
    })
    .getElementSize('#ms-input',function(err,size){
      expect(err).to.be.null
      expect(size.width).to.be.equal(184)
    })
    .execute('return jQuery', function(err,jquery) {
      expect(err).to.be.null
      expect(jquery).not.to.be.undefined
      expect(jquery).not.to.be.null
    })
    .execute('return app', function(err,appInstance) {
      expect(err).to.be.null
      expect(appInstance).not.to.be.undefined
      expect(appInstance).not.to.be.null
    })
    .call(done);
  })

  after(function(done) {
    client.end(done); // ends session and closes the browser
  })
});
```

(**) I already followed the instructions in [Selenium WebDriver JS - Explicit Wait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16882860/selenium-webdriver-js-explicit-wait), but the error is `Object #<WebdriverIO> has no method 'wait'` (which makes perfect sense...)

Comment: WebdriverIO wait commands are called differently - if you just want to wait an x amount of time use the [pause](http://webdriver.io/api/utility/pause.html) command, if you want to wait on some conditions check out the [waitFor](http://webdriver.io/api/utility/waitFor.html) commands

Comment: My take (am I right?) is that all those commands wait for something related to the DOM, whereas I only need to wait for a JS global variable to be set. I guess I'll put a createElement at the end of my init routine and wait for the appearance of that element from the test.