# How to wait for a function to be called when testing using Selenium WebDriver/Jest?

Tags: javascript, testing, selenium-webdriver, extjs, jestjs

I have an application that I created using Ext JS and I am writing tests for it using Selenium WebDriver (the [Node package](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/) - version 4.0.0-alpha.1) and Jest. In one of my test scripts, I want to wait for a function to be called before continuing with the remaining test logic but I am not sure how to implement this. To help demonstrate what I am trying to accomplish, I created a sample app using Sencha Fiddle. All of the code for that app as well as a running version of the app can be found here: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2o6m. If you look in the app folder of the fiddle, you'll see that there is a Test component with a simple controller. There is an onAdd function in the controller and that is the function I want to wait for before continuing since in my actual application there is code in that function that the rest of the tests are dependent on. I can access that function in dev tools by running the following line of code: Ext.ComponentQuery.query('test')[0].getController().onAdd (note that the activeElement needs to be set to the preview iFrame (document.getElementsByName('fiddle-run-iframe')[0]) in the fiddle for this to work). This means I can access the function in driver.executeScript the same way, but once I have the function, I am not sure how to wait for it to be called before continuing. I was trying to use the mock/spy feature in Jest, but this is not working because jest is not defined inside driver.executeScript so I can't call jest.fn or jest.spyOn. I created a sample test script that works with the sample app to demonstrate what I am trying to do, but right now it fails with an error since, as I said, jest is not defined inside driver.executeScript. Here is the code for the sample test script:

```
const {Builder, By, Key, until} = require('selenium-webdriver');
const chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');

const driver = global.driver = new Builder()
            .forBrowser('chrome')
            .setChromeOptions(new chrome.Options())
            .build();

jest.setTimeout(10000);

beforeAll(async () => {
    await driver.manage().window().maximize();
    await driver.get('https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2o6m');
});

afterAll(async () => {
    await driver.quit();
});


describe('check title', () => {
    it('should be SAMPLE STORE LOAD', async () => {
        expect(await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.css('.fiddle-title'))).getText()).toBe('SAMPLE STORE LOAD');
    });
});

describe('check store add', () => {
    it('should call add function', async () => {
        let spy;

        await driver.switchTo().frame(await driver.findElement(By.name('fiddle-run-iframe')));
        await driver.wait(until.elementIsNotVisible(await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.xpath('//div[starts-with(@id, "loadmask")]')))));
        await driver.executeScript(() => {
            const test = document.getElementsByName('fiddle-run-iframe')[0].contentWindow.Ext.ComponentQuery.query('test')[0];
            spy = jest.spyOn(test.getController(), 'onAdd'); //This throws an error since jest is not defined inside driver.executeScript
        });

        expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled(); //wait for onAdd function to be called before continuing
    });

    //additional tests occur here after wait...
});
```

You can ignore all the logic related to switching to the iFrame because that is only necessary for the fiddle since it runs the preview of the app in an iFrame. My actual app does not exist inside an iFrame. Nonetheless, I think this script effectively demonstrates what I am trying to accomplish which is to wait until the onAdd function is called before continuing with my tests. I am not sure if I need to use Selenium or Jest, some combination of the two, or a different testing tool entirely to do this. I am relatively new to writing tests and this is my first time posting on Stack Overflow so I apologize if anything I said is unclear. I would be happy to clarify anything if you have any questions and grateful for any advice you have to offer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my point of view, combining 2 different frameworks (approaches to testing) in a single test might not be the best idea. Here are some thoughts on how I would deal with a similar case. Very little theory:

*Selenium* - is great in simulation end-user behavior with a browser. Basically, it can simulate actions (clicks, text inputs, etc.) and can get information from a browser window (presence of elements, texts, styles, etc.)

*Jest* - is a **unit** test framework to jest javascript code.

`executeScript` is a method of Selenium, it executes any javascript code in a browser. Browser **does not know** anything about `jest` - so it's expected that you faced an error you described. Your project knows about `jest`, as it's specifically imported in a project.

Back to the question ***"How to check in Selenium that a js function has been called?"***

1. The most typical solution - is to wait until something has changed on a browser screen. Typical cases:

   - some element appears
   - some element disappears
   - some element's style changed

[wait for condition in js example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16882860/selenium-webdriver-js-explicit-wait)

2. (a bit of a hack) Another possible solution is to add a some flag in the js code of an app that will be false before function is called and will be set to true after function is called. Then you can access this flag's value in the executeScript.

[some possible implementations here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786851/define-global-variable-in-a-javascript-function)

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. That makes sense why I cannot use Jest code in Selenium. I figured that I would have to wait for a change in the DOM but listening for the function would have been easier since the app I'm working on has dynamic ids. But I guess I'll have to come up with a workaround for that. Thanks again for your help and taking the time to answer my question!

Comment: you're welcome! glad that I was able to help. a potential workaround for dynamic id's is adding a special attribute for elements (if your dev team is willing to make your automation life easier, of course).  for example, we agreed to add custom attribute 'data-seleniumid' and use it in cssSelectors.