# Google search page "next" span with selenium-webdriver & nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am trying to set up following actions with Selenium-Webdriver and NodeJs:

- Open Firefox
- Go to Google.com
- Search a name in Google
- Wait for the page to load
- Select and click the next to the second page.

I am stuck on the last step and have searched similar questions on StackOverflow, but none of the answers have allowed me to locate the  or  tags for "next" or "page 2". I even copied the completed XPath through inspection, but always received "NoSuchElementError".

Thank you for your help.

```
const { Builder, By, Key, until, Wait } = require('selenium-webdriver');

require('geckodriver');
const faker = require('faker');

const searchGoogle = async () => {
    let name = faker.name.findName();
    let driver = await new Builder().forBrowser('firefox').build();

    try {
        await driver
            .manage()
            .window()
            .maximize();
        await driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();

        await driver.get('http://google.com');
        await driver.findElement(By.name('q')).sendKeys(name, Key.RETURN);
        await driver.wait(until.titleIs(name), 1000);
        await driver
            .findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'Next')]"))
            .click();
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    } finally {
        driver.quit();
        console.log('complete!');
    }
};

searchGoogle();
```

Comment: Try experimenting with Wait, wait until this 'Next' is displayed or clickable.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16882860/selenium-webdriver-js-explicit-wait. Locator is definitely correct, just tried in python and it clicked on it for me.

Comment: @tony i think the issue is that the next button is not in the view , write a script to scroll down in the page before executing the click event .

Comment: @subbu, thank you so much. I made the script to do just that based on your suggestion. It works for the most part; however, I still need to use "Wait" for the page to load, I think. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments, I added "Wait" and "Scroll down", and the code can

- Goes to Google,
- Search a name
- Wait for Searched Page to load, Wait for Scroll to Bottom, Wait for next span to click()

```
const { Builder, By, Key, until } = require('selenium-webdriver');

require('geckodriver');
const faker = require('faker');

const searchGoogle = async () => {
    let name = faker.name.findName();
    let driver = await new Builder().forBrowser('firefox').build();

    try {
        await driver
            .manage()
            .window()
            .maximize();
        await driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();

        await driver.get('https://www.google.com/');
        await driver.findElement(By.name('q')).sendKeys(name, Key.RETURN);

        await driver.wait(() => {
            until.titleIs(`${name}  - Google Search`);
            driver.executeScript('window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)');
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'Next')]")).click();
        }, 1000);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    } finally {
        // driver.quit();
        console.log('complete!');
    }
};

searchGoogle();
```

However, now instead of just click the next once to page two, the page goes to page three. I can't really figure the reason behind this. Selenium-webdriver documentation is not very clear on how to use ".wait".